# On page load, send/simulate a key combo [CTRL+L]

Tags: javascript, key, keypress, onload

On page load, send/simulate a key combo [CTRL+L] or [CTRL+L+BACKSPACE] to focus on the URL address bar and or clear it (with focus).

This is for a page to replace the default New Tab in Chrome and other browsers.

The reasoning is that by default when you open a new tab, your URL address bar is focused automatically and it is clear for you to start typing immediately.

This is a problem in this new tab replacement page since it now stops you from being able to just start typing, which is a big habit for Chrome users. They start typing to bring up a auto-completed URL address or to go a fast Google search.

I've spent the last hour and a half Google searching websites, Stack-overflow, and others looking for if this has been done, I haven't found a single result that I could find, at least not one where I had to subscribe to a payment thing to view the answer.

I know activating a key on page load is possible. I know doing a key combo is possible. I want to mix the two together to have on page load have the script simulate the key combo and it causes the browser to focus on it's URL address bar.

Project page if it helps: http://flatline.in/tab/

Answer (score 1):

Well, to be honest, I hope this cannot be done by Javascript.

If developers can modify desktop and/or browser behavior by just using Javascript then it would become really easy to write hacks and malware code.

Answer (score 0):

I found it actually... I usually find something just after I ask a question ... my brain works better then :)

It can be done via Extension in Chrome.

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { 'url': url, 'selected': true });
        });
```

'selected': true is the key to success :)